# How to use 'allThread' in jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I have requirement where after 10 simultaneous users all the users should be diverted to waiting screen. If there are less then 10 simultaneous users then 
dont show waiting screen.

I want to use current thread or all thread in my script for same.
I guess allThread can be used to achieve the same.

It would be good help if answers are with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can get the number of active threads in the current Thread Group using __groovy() function like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumberOfThreads(),)}
   ```

   [image: JMeter Groovy Active Threads]

   This way you will be able to determine the currrent number of active threads and execute this or that code line using i.e. [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) basing on the received number.
2. You can use [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to pause threads execution until specified number of threads will be available in order to kick them off simultaneously. This way you will be sure that desired amount of threads are active at the given moment of time.